# Scala & Play: route regex without identifier

Tags: regex, scala, playframework-2.0

I'd like to provide optional plurality to my routes in a Play application.  For example:

```
/path/1
/paths/1
```

The route URL I tried was something like this:

```
/path<[s?]>/:id
```

If I put just a $ in front of it, it asks for an identifier; if I given it an identifier, it tells me I need to use it in the call definition.  Is what I'm trying to do possible without having to do a Cartesian product of every possibly with/out combination of plurality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If my understanding of the [RoutesCompiler](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/routes-compiler/src/main/scala/play/router/RoutesCompiler.scala) is correct (especially the `check` function), any dynamic part in the URL **must** be used in the call definition.

So it looks like the only option is adding a new parameter like this:

```
GET    /$p<paths?>/:id         controllers.PathController.get(p, id)
GET    /otherpath$p<s?>/:id    controllers.OtherController.get(p, id)
```

Then just ignore the `p` parameter. You will need to provide it when using reverse routes though.

Answer (score 4):

You will have to follow the compiler rule to compose the route.

[Playframework Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaRouting)

**Dynamic parts with custom regular expressions**
You can also define your own regular expression for the dynamic part, using the $id syntax:

```
GET   /clients/$id<[0-9]+>  controllers.Clients.show(id: Long)
```

In your case, try the following:

```
GET     /results/$departure</?.+>           @controllers.SearchController.results(departure: String)
```

However, you might need to make sure this path doesn't overlap with the other routes.